# PHP code - Saving variables, not just cookies on one PC

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

One of my project is to have someone being able to select options on this HTML page and then to have the person click "enter" and it updates the URL of the new tab. The key to this is to have the information saved to the PHP session so if someone else enter the same PHP URL, the variables will still be there in the message, not just saved on one PC. This is where I need assistance.

Can someone look at my PHP code and tell me what I'm not doing right?

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function dynamicdropdown(listindex) {
     document.getElementById('senator').className = listindex;
   }
   </script>
   
   <style>
   optgroup {
     display: none;
   }

   select.agriculture 
   optgroup.agriculture,
   select.appropriations 
   optgroup.appropriations
  
   {
     display: block;
   }
   
   div#header{
   padding: 1px;
   color: yellow;
   padding-left: 9px;
   background-color: #000080;
   }
   
   .category_div{
   padding: 3px;
   }
   
   .sub_category_div{
   padding: 3px;
   }
   
   .microphone{
   padding: 3px;
   }
   
   .category_div_1{
   padding: 3px;
   }
   
   .body{
   padding-right: 5px;
   }

   </style>
 </head>
 
<body>

 <div class="header" id="header">
 <h1>Testing Header</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="room130">
 <h3>Room 130</h3>
 <form target="Room 130" action = "test.php" method="POST">
  <div class="category_div" id="category_div">Committee:
   <select id="committee" name="committee" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="">Select Committee</option>
    <option value="agriculture">AGRICULTURE</option>
    <option value="appropriations">APPROPRIATIONS</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">
  Individual:
   <select name="senator" id="senator">
    <option value="">Select individual</option>
     <optgroup class="agriculture">
      <option value="THE CHAIR">THE CHAIR</option>
      <option value="THE PRESENTER">THE PRESENTER</option>
     </optgroup>
   </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="microphone" id="microphone">Microphone:
   <select id="microphone" name = "microphone">
    <option value=" "> </option>
    <option value="ON">ON</option>
    <option value="OFF">OFF</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  
  </form>
 </div>
```

PHP CODE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Room 130</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready( function() {
 $('#java').delay("90000").fadeOut();
  });
</script>
<style>
 body {
   background-color: #000080;
   color: white;
   font-size: 72px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   height: 100%;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 .java {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 200px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="java" id="java">
 <?php 
 
 $_SESSION["senator"] = $_POST["senator"];
 $_SESSION["microphone"] = $_POST["microphone"];
 
 echo "Please remind ". $_SESSION["senator"]. " to make sure their microphone is " .$_SESSION["microphone"]. ". Thank you."; 
 
 ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sessions are a per user server side storage.  Anything saved in one session for a user will be unavailable to other users.  It looks like you want to store your info somewhere else like a database and retrieve that information on page load.

Comment: You might want to consider using memcached or Redis. If it is not an option, store data in database or in a text file somewhere on filesystem

Comment: @SymeonQuimby all four PC's are connected on the same server, just located in different rooms.

Comment: 1 session is for 1 web browser on 1 computer :)
TO achive what you what you have to use file/database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to store and retrieve session variables, you need to start the session with [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

Second, session identifier is stored locally in cookies, any attempts to circumvent this and use the same session for multiple users would present serious troubles and possibly security vulnerabilities, it's just not worth it.

If you need to store values server-side, consider using a database. For exceptionally simple tasks you may also use flat text storage, but it is usually not recommended.

Now, when it comes to the particular task you're trying to achieve, it looks like HTTP GET variables are exactly what you need:

In the first page replace this line:

```
<form target="Room 130" action = "test.php" method="POST">
```

With this:

```
<form target="Room 130" action="test.php" method="GET">
```

In `test.php` replace these lines:

```
$_SESSION["senator"] = $_POST["senator"];
$_SESSION["microphone"] = $_POST["microphone"];
echo "Please remind ". $_SESSION["senator"]. " to make sure their microphone is " .$_SESSION["microphone"]. ". Thank you.";
```

With these:

```
$senator = $_GET['senator'];
$microphone = $_GET['microphone'];
echo "Please remind ". $senator. " to make sure their microphone is " .$microphone. ". Thank you.";
```

In case if `test.php` is not only accessed by submitting the form on the first page, you may want to check if the variables are there:

```
if(isset($_GET['senator']) && isset($_GET['microphone'])) {
    $senator = $_GET['senator'];
    $microphone = $_GET['microphone'];
    echo "Please remind ". $senator. " to make sure their microphone is " .$microphone. ". Thank you.";
} else {
    // Do something when the page is accessed without any GET variables in the url
}
```

If you do this, then when you access `test.php?senator=Jon&microphone=12`, the page will output the following:

> Please remind Jon to make sure their microphone is 12. Thank you.

**EDIT:** Another option is text storage.

Create file `data.txt` in the same folder that contains `test.php` and set permissions to `0666`.

In `test.php` replace these lines:

```
$_SESSION["senator"] = $_POST["senator"];
$_SESSION["microphone"] = $_POST["microphone"];
echo "Please remind ". $_SESSION["senator"]. " to make sure their microphone is " .$_SESSION["microphone"]. ". Thank you.";
```

With these:

```
if(isset($_POST["senator"]) && isset($_POST["microphone"])) { // If the page receives POST data, it needs to be stored
    $senator = $_POST["senator"];
    $microphone = $_POST["microphone"];
    $data = json_encode(Array($senator, $microphone)); // Put values into an array and encode it for storage
    file_put_contents('data.txt', $data); // Put the JSON-encoded array into a text file. This function replaces the contents of the text file, which is exactly what is needed in this application. To append instead of replacing the contents, you need a FILE_APPEND flag.
} else { // If there's no POST data, the values are retrieved from the storage
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.txt')); // Retrieve the contents of the text file and decode them back into an array
    $senator = $data[0];
    $microphone = $data[1];
}
echo "Please remind ". $senator. " to make sure their microphone is " .$microphone. ". Thank you.";
```

**EDIT 2:** If you use text storage solution above and want to dynamically update the page with JS, I'd suggest using jQuery.

Since we already store values in the text file, it's logical to just access the same file in JS as well, though you can not access it locally due to security concerns, it has to be accessed like a remote resource.

Add this JS function to your page:

```
function updateData() {
    $.getJSON("https://website.com/data.txt", function(data) {
        var senator = data[0];
        var microphone = data[1];
        $("#java").text("Please remind " + senator + " to make sure their microphone is " + microphone + ". Thank you.");
    });
}
```

And call it whenever you want to update the data. You can put it into a loop or call it on click.

Comment: I don't believe GET is the method I need to use? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I need the two variable saved so then I could just update the information on the website without having the page to refresh which will be done using JS

Comment: I may have misunderstood the problem. Is test.php going to always output the same data for everyone who accesses it, or do you need to output different values for different users?

Comment: test.php is going to one room, but I need the data to change because if "Zac" microphone is "13" i need the variables to change from "Jon" to "Zac" and "12" to "13".

Comment: I updated the answer with a flat text storage solution, seems like it's what you're looking for, though it will get more complicated if you want the page to dynamically update the data whenever there's a change.

Comment: Can't I just do that with a JS script? to have the data update without having the entire page to refresh?

Comment: I updated the answer with a JS function that will work in conjunction with the flat text storage solution in the first edit.

Comment: sorry for so many questions, I can use a button on my HTML page to update the js? if not then it's fine, i'll just loop it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138261/discussion-between-dmitry-ponkin-and-albert-tung).